# Optimize spaCy named entity recognition for precision

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am currently working on a NER task where precision is more important than recall. To train the model I am using the cli command `python -m spacy train en . train.json dev.json`. As far as I know it optimizes for the f1 score. Is it possible to optimize for f0.5 score using this cli command?

Answer (score 0):

try to change the hyperparameters
https://spacy.io/api/cli#train-hyperparams